# ReactJS - Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, onclick, preventdefault

Trying to do a simple onClick event/function, in ReactJS.

When the button is clicked, I want to run a function called "onClick", but I get this error in console:

```
app.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined
```

Have googled, but not sure what I'm going wrong.  I've looked at ReactJs documentation and this looks correct, but obviously not.  Here's my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Header from './components/Header';
import GiphyButton from './components/GiphyButton';
import './assets/sass/main.scss';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      giphy: []
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log('giffy button clicked');
    axios.get('http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?q=otters&api_key=<API KEY>')

      .then(res => {
        this.setState({ giphy: res.data });
        console.log(res.data);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
          <Navbar />
          <Header />
          <GiphyButton onClick={this.handleClick()}/>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

GiphyButton is a component, which is literally, just JSX for a  . No other functions running here:

import React from 'react';

```
const GiphyButton = () => (

  <section>
    <button>See more otters</button>
  </section>
);

export default GiphyButton;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the answer to my question, but I ended up changing the function to handleSubmit and passing this into a form, which my button sits in.  This worked.

Answer (score 4):

You should bind this event  to "handleClick()" function. As follows,

```
<GiphyButton onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>
```

Comment: It's not generally recommended to bind ```this``` to functions here.  It's better to use arrow functions which already have the correct ```this``` in scope or do what you have here in the constructor. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 3):

You should just pass function -`handleClick` and not call it

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <main>
          <Navbar />
          <Header />
          <GiphyButton handleClick={this.handleClick}/>
        </main>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
```

That was preventing event object to be passed causing `undefined` error.

Change code for `GiphyButton` with following to pass onclick method -

```
import React from 'react';

const GiphyButton = (props) => (

  <section>
    <button onClick={props.handleClick}>See more otters</button>
  </section>
);

export default GiphyButton;
```

Comment: HI @Vivek - I did try that before.  I dont receive an error in console, but the button doesn't work.  If I click on it the function doesn't run at all...

Comment: @ReenaVerma i've added code for `GiphyButton` as well so that it will call `handleClick` function

Comment: does button need to sit in a form?

Answer (score 1):

inside the onclick function you have pass event as you calling it.
Like ,

`onClick={(e)=>this.handleClick(e)}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the solution of Vivek is correct. the reason why it seems not to run might be your missing error handling. check the url (maybe something wrong with api key?) and try catching axios errors. take a look here:

[code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-c3inmd)

Comment: Ok, so I've tried catching the errors and nothing console logs.  the button just doesn't seem to run the function at all.  I know the approach is correct, but I'm not sure what else is running, other than the original error I was getting...

Comment: can you post your current code? what is different from the code example that i sent?

Comment: Hi @ugrpla - it's exactly as above.  However my button jsx, doesn't sit in the same file.  It sits in a seperate component called "GiphyButton". You can see I'm calling it here: import GiphyButton from './components/GiphyButton';

Comment: Hi @ReenaVerma - if it's exactly like above, then your button component in GiphyButton has no onClick at all. Pass the clickHandler as property down to your GiphyButton, and call it with `<button onClick={props.handleClick}>See more otters</button>`